# MYSQL sorting by HAVING distance but not able to group?

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT zip, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(34.12520) ) * cos( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( zip_info.longitude ) - radians(-118.29200) ) + sin( radians(34.12520) ) * sin( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, 
user_info.*, office_locations.* 

FROM zip_info 

RIGHT JOIN office_locations ON office_locations.zipcode = zip_info.zip 

RIGHT JOIN user_info ON office_locations.doctor_id = user_info.id 

WHERE user_info.status='yes' 

HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

It outputs

distance | doctor_id  |  etc.

7  ---------------   5 ------- etc

8  ---------------   4 ------- etc

34  ---------------   4 ------- etc

49  ---------------   5 ------- etc

When I select a distance of 30 or less, it shows the top two results as well, which is good.

The Problem : I do not want to show more than one result per doctor_id so I do a GROUP BY user_info.doctor_id, which shows no results when distance is less than 50. For some reason it wants to have all the results to group otherwise it won't work. Any tips? Anything else you need to help me out?

So What I want is

distance | doctor_id  |  etc.

7  ---------------   5 ------- etc

8  ---------------   4 ------- etc

Even though it wants to give me all 4 rows for results, I just want to group them so only the ones with smallest distance per unique user_info.doctor_id show up. Keep in mind distance is a virtual non existent table.

---

Based on llion's query here are the results:

```
 (concat(user_info.id))     zip     distance    id
          1                 NULL    6.6643992   1
```

It only gives one result, and in order to get it to work, I had to change the AND to HAVING distance again.

Comment: Your current having should be a `where`... you're might be unintentionally doing a group by currently...

Comment: In this case, there's no problem with the `HAVING` in place of the `WHERE`, the difference is when the predicate is applied.  (A WHERE clause limits the rows included, the HAVING clause gets run as almost the last step in the plan, and limits only the rows returned.)

Comment: When I do WHERE with distance, it says that column does not exist (probably because it's virtually created and not an actual column, perhaps I don't understand mysql that well yet if that's not the case). Using WHERE would be all I need but no results show up unless I use HAVING

Comment: +1, if only for the implementation of the great circle calculation. Your use of HAVING is appropriate. To use a WHERE, you would need to repeat the "distance" expression, rather than refer to the column alias. Contrary to popular opinion, the HAVING clause does NOT cause a GROUP BY operation nor does it invoke aggregate functions, although it is quite useful in queries with aggregates and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe a GROUP BY is going to give you the result you want.  And unfortunately, MySQL does not support analytic functions (which is how we would solve this problem in Oracle or SQL Server.)

It's possible to emulate some rudimentary analytic functions, by making use of user-defined variables.

In this case, we want to emulate:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY doctor_id ORDER BY distance ASC) AS seq
```

So, starting with the original query, I changed the ORDER BY so that it sorts on `doctor_id` first, and then on the calculated `distance`.  (Until we know those distances, we don't know which one is "closest".)

With this sorted result, we basically "number" the rows for each doctor_id, the closest one as 1, the second closest as 2, and so on. When we get a new doctor_id, we start again with the closest as 1.

To accomplish this, we make use of user-defined variables. We use one for assigning the row number (the variable name is @i, and returned column has the alias seq). The other variable we use to "remember" the doctor_id from the previous row, so we can detect a "break" in the doctor_id, so we can know when to restart the row numbering at 1 again.

Here's the query:

---

```
SELECT z.*
, @i := CASE WHEN z.doctor_id = @prev_doctor_id THEN @i + 1 ELSE 1 END AS seq
, @prev_doctor_id := z.doctor_id AS prev_doctor_id
FROM
(

  /* original query, ordered by doctor_id and then by distance */
  SELECT zip, 
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(34.12520) ) * cos( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( zip_info.longitude ) - radians(-118.29200) ) + sin( radians(34.12520) ) * sin( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, 
  user_info.*, office_locations.* 
  FROM zip_info 
  RIGHT JOIN office_locations ON office_locations.zipcode = zip_info.zip 
  RIGHT JOIN user_info ON office_locations.doctor_id = user_info.id 
  WHERE user_info.status='yes' 
  ORDER BY user_info.doctor_id ASC, distance ASC

) z JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @prev_doctor_id := NULL) i
HAVING seq = 1 ORDER BY z.distance
```

---

I'm making an assumption that the original query is returning the result set you need, it just has too many rows, and you want to eliminate all but the "closest" (the row with the minimum value of distance) for each doctor_id.

I've wrapped your original query in another query; the only changes I made to the original query was to order the results by doctor_id and then by distance, and to remove the `HAVING distance < 50` clause.  (If you only want to return distances less than 50, then go ahead and leave that clause there. It wasn't clear whether that was your intent, or whether that was specified in an attempt to limit rows to one per doctor_id.)

A couple of issues to note:

The replacement query returns two additional columns; these aren't really needed in the result set, except as means to generate the result set.  (It's possible to wrap this whole SELECT again in another SELECT to omit those columns, but that is really more messy than it's worth. I would just retrieve the columns, and know that I can ignore them.)

The other issue is that the use of the `.*` in the inner query is a bit dangerous, in that we really need to guarantee that the column names returned by that query are unique. (Even if the column names are distinct right now, the addition of a column to one of those tables could introduce an "ambiguous" column exception in the query. It's best to avoid that, and that's easily addressed by replacing the `.*` with the list of columns to be returned, and specifying an alias for any "duplicate" column name. (The use of the `z.*` in the outer query is not a concern, as long as we are in control of the columns returned by `z`.)

---

**Addendum:**

I noted that a GROUP BY wasn't going to give you the result set you needed. While it would be possible to get the result set with a query using GROUP BY, a statement that returns the CORRECT result set would be tedious. You could specify `MIN(distance) ... GROUP BY doctor_id`, and that would get you the smallest distance, BUT there is no guarantee that the other non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list would be from the row with the minimum distance, and not some other row. (MySQL is dangerously liberal in regards to GROUP BY and aggregates. To get the MySQL engine to be more cautious (and in line with other relational database engines), `SET sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

**Addendum 2:**

Performance Issues reported by Darious "some queries take 7 seconds."

To speed things up, you probably want to cache the results of the function. Basically, build a lookup table. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE office_location_distance
( office_location_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK to office_location.id'
, zipcode_id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK to zipcode.id'
, gc_distance        DECIMAL(18,2)         COMMENT 'calculated gc distance, in miles'
, PRIMARY KEY (office_location_id, zipcode_id)
, KEY (zipcode_id, gc_distance, office_location_id)
, CONSTRAINT distance_lookup_office_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (office_location_id) REFERENCES office_location(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT distance_lookup_zipcode_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (zipcode_id) REFERENCES zipcode(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

That's just an idea. (I expect that you are searching for office_location distance from a particular zipcode, so the index on (zipcode, gc_distance, office_location_id) is the covering index your query would need. (I would avoid storing the calculated distance as a FLOAT, due to poor query performance with FLOAT datatype)

```
INSERT INTO office_location_distance (office_location_id, zipcode_id, gc_distance)
SELECT d.office_location_id
     , d.zipcode_id
     , d.gc_distance
  FROM (
         SELECT l.id AS office_location_id
              , z.id AS zipcode_id
              , ROUND( <glorious_great_circle_calculation> ,2) AS gc_distance
           FROM office_location l
          CROSS
           JOIN zipcode z
          ORDER BY 1,3
       ) d
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gc_distance = VALUES(gc_distance)
```

With the function results cached and indexed, your queries should be much faster.

```
SELECT d.gc_distance, o.*
  FROM office_location o
  JOIN office_location_distance d ON d.office_location_id = o.id
 WHERE d.zipcode_id = 63101
   AND d.gc_distance <= 100.00
 ORDER BY d.zipcode_id, d.gc_distance
```

I am hesitant about adding a HAVING predicate on the INSERT/UPDATE to the cache table; (if you had a wrong latitude/longitude, and had calculated an erroneous distance under 100 miles; a subsequent run after the lat/long is fixed and the distance works out to 1000 miles... if the row is excluded from the query, then existing row in the cache table won't get updated. (You could clear the cache table, but that's not really necessary, that's just a lot of extra work for the database and logs.  If the result set of the maintenance query is too large, it could be broken down to run iteratively for each zipcode, or each office_location.)

On the other hand, if you aren't interested in any distances over a certain value, you could add the `HAVING gc_distance <` predicate, and cut down the size of the cache table considerably.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and tedious query work! I was able to alter some more things and got it to work, I've never seen mysql used like this with @i variables and such. Thank you!

Comment: @Darius: there are some significant caveats with using the user-defined variables: limited datatype support, basically integer and strings (including strings representing dates), issues with collation, and I ONLY use them in SELECT statements, not in DML (because the order of operations in a DML statement is not guaranteed.)  (I have inserted the results of a SELECT like this into an empty work table, and then referenced the work table in other DML operations.)  Also, future versions of MySQL may change the behavior - these are not standard SQL.

Comment: I've been testing it more and noticed a significant drop in speed, some take up to 7 seconds to complete. :( Any tips? I have 3 tables, the doctors info, the doctors locations (latitude and longitude) and the zipcodes (several thousand of them).

Comment: Can you think of any better solution?

Comment: @Darius: to speed this up, you really want to avoid recalculating the distance between zip codes and office locations on every query. If you want performance of queries, one approach is a cache table, where you cache the results of the function. It will be a large number of rows, but if you keep the rows as short as possible (just keys to the doctors locations and the zip code table, and the ordinal position (1=closest, 2=second closest), that could speed up queries. You would need to maintain that table, but that could be done offline ...

Comment: @Darius: I updated my answer, to include an example of a cache table to hold the function results.

Answer (score 1):

The HAVING clause filters based on aggregate results. When you add your GROUP BY into the statement then the equations that make up the `distance` column add values for all rows for single doctor_id. Therefore the distances would end up being:

```
distance | doctor_id | etc
      56 |         5 | etc
      42 |         4 | etc
```

As you can see, doctor_id 5 is > 50. If doctor_id 4 is not returning results then I'd assume there's more rows you didn't show.

What you want are the distinct doctor_ids with distances of less than 50. Do you want the minimum, maximum, average distance? Maybe this is what you want (I have not tested this and I think you'll need to work out grouping around the zip values):

```
SELECT distinct(concat(zip,user_info.doctor_id)), zip, min(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(34.12520) ) * cos( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) * cos(radians( zip_info.longitude ) - radians(-118.29200) ) + sin( radians(34.12520) ) * sin( radians( zip_info.latitude ) ) ) )) AS distance, 
user_info.doctor_id

FROM zip_info 

RIGHT JOIN office_locations ON office_locations.zipcode = zip_info.zip 

RIGHT JOIN user_info ON office_locations.doctor_id = user_info.id 

WHERE user_info.status='yes' 
AND distance < 50 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

That should provide unique zip/doctor groupings without adding in other things.

Comment: I didn't say the HAVING clause caused it. I said the GROUP by did. I did see I dropped a thought. I meant to say HAVING groups by aggregates where as WHERE filters single rows.

Comment: @llion: what you meant to say, that "HAVING groups by aggregates", is just not an accurate description of the behavior of the HAVING clause. The HAVING clause can be applied to non-aggregates as well.

Comment: Apparently I can't properly get a thought out to the keyboard! You are right of course. I should have said HAVING is for filtering by aggregates, not grouping. Obviously you can use it on non-aggregate rows as well but I don't know why you would.

Comment: The query in the question makes use of the HAVING clause, as a predicate on an expression.  The advantage of HAVING (in this case) is that it can reference the column alias; `HAVING distance <

Comment: There HAVING clause being replaced with AND causes it to stop working. When we use AND it looks for an actual existing column named distance which doesn't exist, we have it as a virtual table. It only works when we use HAVING, but even then it gives wrong structure of results. I updated the question based on your query.