# Mysql - distance parameter search finding all targets within distance of central location using individual preference

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial

This is a tough one to explain.  I'm able to find all zipcodes within a radius of x miles.  However what I want to do is find all Userids from tblUsers whos MaxDistance is <= x zipcode.

So in plain english I want to know all the people who are within a zipcode radius based on their `MaxDistance`

For example I have a table:

```
tblUsers(ID int, Maxdistance int,Zipcode varchar(5))
1|50|94129
2|25|94111
3|100|19019
```

In my second table:

```
tblTmpPlaces(ID int,Zipcode varchar(5))
1|94129
```

What I want to do is using tblTmpPlaces zipcode, I want to be able to say hey users 1 and 2 are within their max distance and select these.  However user 3's max distance is 100 and not close enough to tblTmpPlaces zipcode of 94129.  94129 is San Fran, and 19019 is Philadelphia.  The user is over 100 miles from San Fran.

This is what i've been using to get the distance but this uses a central location to find all within an area but it doesn't take into consideration MaxDistance.  Any help is appreciated.

So basically `select ID from tblUsers where` this is the part i'm stumbling on

```
SELECT Zipcode
             FROM tblZipcodes
            WHERE (  3959
                   * acos(
                            cos(
                               radians(
                                  @XLocationParam))
                          * cos(
                               radians(
                                  x(location)))
                          * cos(
                                 radians(
                                    y(location))
                               - radians(
                                    @YLocationParam))
                        +   sin(
                               radians(
                                  @XLocationParam))
                          * sin(
                               radians(
                                  x(location)))) <= 30))
```

Comment: Mike, can you show us the expected output based on your this data above? :)

Comment: Only MySQL or is it possible to use PHP in the background? I'd prefer PHP, otherwise one would need subquerys.

Comment: @JamesCameron only MySQL

Comment: @bonCodigo  ~I want to be able to say hey users 1 and 2 are within their max distance and select these you'd get users 1/2 in the select

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you need the latitude and longitude for the "center" of each zipcode.  Without that, MySQL can't calculate the distance between the zip codes.

```
tblZipcodeLatLong
( Zipcode   varchar(5)
, latitude  decimal(7,4)
, longitude decimal(7,4)
)
```

Then you could calculate the distance between all of the Zipcodes, using your Great Circle Distance (GCD) formula.

For performance, though, you'll likely not want to do that in each individual query, but rather, you'd want to pre-calculate the distance between all the Zipcodes, and have those calculated distances stored in a table.

```
SELECT p1.Zipcode AS p1_Zipcode
     , p2.Zipcode AS p2_Zipcode
     , <gcd_formula> AS distance
  FROM tblZipcodeLatLong p1
 CROSS
  JOIN tblZipcodeLatLong p2
```

Where `<gcd_distance>` represents your great circle distance formula that calculates the distance between all of the zipcodes.

A query of this form would return the result set you are looking for:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
  FROM tblTmpPlaces p
  JOIN (
         SELECT p1.Zipcode AS p_Zipcode
              , p2.Zipcode AS u_Zipcode
              , <gcd_formula> AS distance
           FROM tblZipcodeLatLong p1 
          CROSS
           JOIN tblZipcodeLatLong p2
       ) d
    ON d.p_Zipcode = p.Zipcode
  JOIN tblUsers u 
    ON u.Zipcode = d.u_Zipcode
   AND u.Maxdistance >= d.distance
 WHERE p.Zipcode = '94129'
```

As I noted before, doing that cross join operation and calculating all those distances in that subquery (aliased as d) on each query could be quite a bit of overhead.  For performance, you'd likely want those results pre-calculated, stored in an appropriately indexed table, and then replace that subquery with a reference to the pre-populated table.

---

NOTE:

I have a GCD formula in one of the other answers I posted here on stackoverflow a while back. I'll see if I can find it.

Similar question answered here:

[MYSQL sorting by HAVING distance but not able to group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109127/mysql-sorting-by-having-distance-but-not-able-to-group)

Answer (score 0):

Did the exact same thing, if i can understand, u are getting the zipcodes already (possibly in an array) simple thing to do would be to find an match of those zipcodes with the corresponding users using the IN operator in sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE zipcode IN zipcodes_array;
zipcodes_array being the array u already have